# Simulating user input in JUnit test Case

Tags: java, junit

I would like to write a JUnit TestCase for some method that requires user input. Here is part of my method:

```
public void createCart() {
...
myCart= new Cart();
s = console.readLine("Enter your first name: "); 
myCart.setFirst(s);
...
}
```

how can i write a Junit testcase for the above i.e. how can i provide the first name in the TestCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that you are using `java.io.Console` that does not implement any useful interface your only way is to mick it up or to wrap it.

Take a look in mockup java frameworks like EasyMock or Mockito. They allow you to mock any API, i.e. make API to return value you want.

Alternative solution is not to use `Console` directly but create interface with 2 implementations: one based on `Console` for production, other one for tests.

Comment: what can i use other than console to make this easier?

Comment: In addition at what @AlexR said: it's a bad practice to read user inputs inside business methods. My advice is to pass your input(s) as `createCart()` parameters. It will be easier to test it.